# SDWebImage NSURLRequests failing intermittently

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, nsurlrequest, sdwebimage

I'm loading images from a remote server using SDWebImage into a UICollectionView using the following code:

```
[myCell.imageView setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRetryFailed success:^(UIImage *image)
 {
     [_imageCache storeImage:image forKey:[imgURL absoluteString] toDisk:YES];
 } failure:^(NSError *error){
     NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
 }];
```

For most cells, this code works fine - it loads the images and saves them to my local disk. However, after several (it seems random?) images, they stop loading. I then get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1d33fdc0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://path/to/image.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://path/to/image.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1d34c0f0 "The request timed out."}
```

When this happens, my app seems to stop sending NSURLRequests altogether. After a period of time, probably about 20-30 seconds, I can refresh the table and the failed images will load in correctly and the app will resume responding to all NSURLRequests perfectly fine.

I find that this tends to happen more often if I scroll down my collection view fast. Could it be trying to download too many at once? Is there a way to limit the number of concurrent downloads? This method appears to be deprecated in the latest SDWebImage code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was using MWPhotoBrowser in another part of my app. MWPhotoBrowser comes with an older/modified version of SDWebImage. I downloaded the latest version of SDWebImage from Github, renamed/refactored all of the files, and imported my newly updated and modified SDWebImage alongside the one MWPhotoBrowser relies on.

The new version of SDWebImage has solved my problem completely!

Answer (score 0):

It's better if use asynchronous download by share manager and display when finish download with SDWebImage. Now, you can scroll fast to test.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MyCell *myCell = (MyCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //Set placeholder
    myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

    NSURL *cellImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.collectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [myCell.cellIndicator startAnimating];

    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadWithURL:cellImageURL
                    delegate:self
                     options:0
    success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached)
    { 
        //Display when finish download
        myCell.imageView.image = image;
        [myCell.cellIndicator stopAnimating];
    } failure:nil];


    return cell;

}
```

*EDIT:
If problem still not solve on device: try to separate download and display

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (retain , nonatomic) NSMutableArray *linksArray;
@property (retain , nonatomic) NSMutableArray *imagesArray;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initLinksArray];
//Add placehoder.png to your imagesArray
    [self initImagesArray];
//Download to NSMultableArray
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImages) withObject:nil];

}

- (void)initImagesArray{
    self.imagesArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.linksArray.count; i++) {
        [self.imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
}

- (void)downloadImages{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.linksArray.count; i++) {
        NSURL *cellImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.linksArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
        [manager downloadWithURL:cellImageURL
                        delegate:self
                         options:0
                         success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached)
         {
             [self.imagesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:image];
         } failure:nil];
    }
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.imagesArray count];;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SDCell *cell = (SDCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SDCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellImageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method produces the same problems :( Also, both methods work perfectly in the iOS Simulator - it's only on a device where the problems occur. Is there a way to queue only 10 images loading at once, then the next 10, etc?